# Выбрать из массива по одному элементу для каждого id с наименьшим date

Tags: php, массивы, выборка

Подскажите, как правильнее всего на PHP сделать следующую выборку из массива:

```
$arr = array(
            array(
                'id' => '4432',
                'date' => '1494820875'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '0000',
                'date' => '1494820648'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '4432',
                'date' => '1494814180'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '5842',
                'date' => '1494806895'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '0000',
                'date' => '1494804549'
            ),
        );
```

Имеем массив, в котором есть множество элементов с одинаковым `id`. Нужно выбрать отсюда по одному элементу каждого `id` с наименьшим `date`. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Перебираешь массив с помощью `foreach` и сравниваешь значения `date`

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = [...];
$out = [];

foreach($in as $value){
    if (!isset($out[$value['id']]) || $out[$value['id']] > $value['date']){
         $out[$value['id']] = $value['date'];
    }
}
```

В выводе будет массив с ключами `id` и значениями `date`

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = array(
            array(
                'id' => '4432',
                'date' => '1494820875'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '0000',
                'date' => '1494820648'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '4432',
                'date' => '1494814180'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '5842',
                'date' => '1494806895'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '0000',
                'date' => '1494804549'
            ),
);





if($arr){
    $out;
    foreach($arr as $v){
        if(isset($out[$v['id']]) == false){
            $out[$v['id']] = $v;
            continue;
        }

        if($out[$v['id']]['date'] > $v['date']){
            $out[$v['id']] = $v;
        }
    }

    print_r($out);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [4432] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4432
            [date] => 1494814180
        )

    [0000] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0000
            [date] => 1494804549
        )

    [5842] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5842
            [date] => 1494806895
        )

)
```

Или 2, немного помуторнее, но вывод таков (без имен с id).

```
$arr = array(
            array(
                'id' => '4432',
                'date' => '1494820875'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '0000',
                'date' => '1494820648'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '4432',
                'date' => '1494814180'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '5842',
                'date' => '1494806895'
            ),
            array(
                'id' => '0000',
                'date' => '1494804549'
            ),
);





if($arr){
    $newArray;
    foreach($arr as $v){
        if($newArray){
            foreach($newArray as $t){
                if($t['id'] == $v['id']){
                    continue 2;
                    //исключаем уже найденные
                }
            }
        }   

        $old = null;
        foreach($arr as $v2){
            if($v['id'] == $v2['id']){
                if($old == null){
                    $old = $v2;
                    continue;
                }

                if($old['date'] > $v2['date']){
                    $old = $v2;
                }

            }
        }
        $newArray[] = $old;
    }

    print_r($newArray);
}
```

Вывод 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4432
            [date] => 1494814180
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0000
            [date] => 1494804549
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5842
            [date] => 1494806895
        )

)
```