# Выборка уникальных массивов из массива php

Tags: php

Задача стоит следующая. Получен массив содержащий другие массивы, например:

```
$arr = array(
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'заочная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Физика',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        )
    );
```

Из этого набора нужно вытащить только уникальные наборы. Значения во всех поля будут меняться. Собственно не пойму как выбрать массивы основываясь на уникальности нескольких столбцов.

В итоге должен получить массивы:

```
'Химия', 'очная', 'пропуск'
'Химия', 'заочная', 'пропуск'
'Физика', 'очная', 'пропуск'
```

Пробовал через `array_unique($arr);`, но получаю только одну первую запись

Нашел на сайте вопрос про [выборку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688663/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-php), но увы мне не подходит.

Стоит добавить, что во внутренних массивах есть еще столбцы содержащие данные также разные.

Comment: откуда получен?

Comment: изначально из экслеля, потом с ним проводятся еще работы и вот он приходит такой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
        array(
          '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'заочная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Физика',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        )
    );


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

$set[]=$value[0].';'.$value[1].';'.$value[2];

}

foreach ($set as $key1 => $value1) {
    
$res[$value1]=$key1;

}

foreach ($res as $key2 => $value2) {

$main[]=explode(";", $key2);

}

print_r($main);

?>
```

Comment: ну потом еще array_values  сделать, а то неаккуратненько. и непонятно зачем циферки в $key1  $value1 а главное непонятно зачем вообще два цикла

Comment: чтоб он понял))

Comment: я как раз таки вообще не понял

Comment: тут уникальность делается через ключь, т.к два или более одинаковых элемента в ключе массива не может быть, самое простое сделал

Comment: Хм, не пойму а как тогда будет вычисляться ключ?

Comment: я в ключь запихал через точку с запятой слова, и вобще сделай так print_r($set); echo "<br>"; print_r($res); echo "<br>"; print_r($main); echo "<br>"; и всё станет понятно, а птом подумай как можно обойтись без 2 ого цикла $res

Comment: ну вот я сейчас повторил указанный алгоритм, сайт не упал, но уникальные не отобрал

Comment: Значит массив возможно большие маленькие буквы разные у тебя в словах

Comment: Извиняюсь пропустил в одном из циклов вызов нового массива

Comment: но все равно не очень понимаю за счёт чего он выбирает уникальные

Comment: ключи в массиве не могут быть одинаковые $arr=array("0"=>"zero", "0"=>"ноль"); print_r($arr); вот так для обьяснения

Comment: т.е. грубо говоря выборка происходит просто по закону раз ключ уже взят, то второй такой же не возьмем, но тогда определяет он это перебором ключей? Тогда если у меня будет большая сложность при росте числа ключей, нет?

Comment: array unique так же работает, да и не парся я в ключь запихал т.к мне не нужно знать что в значении. я привель ноль что он выберет последний элемент( но это особенность такая, а  в целом на значение в данной ситуации пофиг)

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать сереализовать внутренние массивы, отфильтровать, и сделать обратно десериализацаю. Пример ниже привел:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'заочная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Химия',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        ),
        array(
            '0' => 'Физика',
            '1' => 'очная',
            '2' => 'пропуск'
        )
    );

function _serialize($arr)
{
    return implode("\t", $arr);
}

function _deserialize($data)
{
    return explode("\t", $data);
}

$arr_unique = array_unique(array_map('_serialize', $arr));
$arr_unique = array_map('_deserialize', $arr_unique);

var_dump($arr_unique);
```

Comment: я бы все-таки переписал на анонимные функции. в  2020 как-то уже не солидно отдельно функции создавать :)

Comment: @Ипатьев поменял :-) хотя для овтета принципальной разницы не вижу, человек спрашивал про саму идею, мне просто показалось что так более понятно было, что в том месте нужно написать свою функцию какую-то для сериализации

Comment: ну вообще да, соглашусь, предыдущий вариант был нагляднее

Comment: Сайт не может обработать запрос и больше ничего

Comment: @Александр как версия PHP ? Я здесь проверял, вроде все работает: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ef83a4fbe5f4e92713fa1bb470a6fc2e9111653

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin сейчас узнал, что 5.2.5

Comment: @Александр, сейчас верну тогда вариант, который для старых версий подходит

Comment: @Александр попробуйте сейчас, я пример исправил, он должен и на старых версиях работать

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin сейчас проверил, все также ...

Comment: @Александр тогда логи смотреть. Там думаю будет видно в чем ошибка.

Comment: Проведя еще ряд танцев с бубнами заработало

Comment: @Александр а в чем была проблема ?

Comment: Тупящий интернет